# Trying to pull logs from Github using Java JGit

Tags: java, github, logging, integration, jgit

I'm trying to use JGit to pull a log of commits done by developers using a Github security token. I tried googling a lot, but the documentation is scarce on this. The code that I am currently tinkering with looks like this:

```
public class GitIntegration {
    public GitIntegration() {
    }
    
    public Iterable<RevCommit> getCommits() throws IOException, InvalidRefNameException, GitAPIException {
        FileRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
        repositoryBuilder.setMustExist( true );
        repositoryBuilder.setGitDir( new File ("https://oauth2:xyzxyzTOKENxyzxyz@github.com/myuser/myrepo.git"));
        Repository repository = repositoryBuilder.build();

        try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
            Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();
            int count = 0;
            for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
                System.out.println("LogCommit: " + commit);
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            return commits;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 5:
> https:\oauth2:xyzxyzTOKENxyzxyz@github.com\myuser\myrepo.git\config
> sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)

It doesn't work to throw git syntax in the File constructor like that at all. Does anyone know of a way to authenticate with tokens and then be able to use the git.log() method?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you're trying to open a remote repo directly. `FileRepositoryBuilder::setGitDir` expects the path to a local Git repo. You need to clone the remote repository first. You may try to come up with a series of CLI Git commands to accomplish the task and then translate them to JGit.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a bit, I decided to go with the Kohsuke github library instead. When doing that it was quite straightforward. Posting basic code example for reference. *(Please note that this if for Enterprise Git. If you are doing it for "normal" Git, look into the Kohsuke documentation, you will need to use another method instead of connectToEnterpriseWithOAuth.)*

```
import org.kohsuke.github.*;


public class GitIntegration {
    
    
    public GitIntegration() {
        
    }
    
    
    public String getCommits(String repo) {
        String retval = "";
        try {
            GitHub gitHub = GitHub.connectToEnterpriseWithOAuth("https://git.our.company.com/api/v3", "my.email@ourcompany.com", "xyzxyzTokenxyzxyz");
            GHMyself me = gitHub.getMyself();
            
            GHRepository repository = gitHub.getRepository("Gituser/"+repo);
            
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(2020, 10, 4);
            Date since = cal.getTime();

            GHCommitQueryBuilder queryBuilder = repository.queryCommits().since(since).until(new Date());
            PagedIterable<GHCommit> commits = queryBuilder.list();
            Iterator<GHCommit> iterator = commits.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                GHCommit commit = iterator.next();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                GHUser user = commit.getAuthor();
                String name = "";
                if(user != null) name = user.getName();
                String message = commit.getCommitShortInfo().getMessage();
                retval = retval.concat(message + " | " + name + " | " + sdf.format(commit.getCommitDate()) + "\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            retval = e.getCause().getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```